# How to drive an IGBT with an optocoupler?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, msp430, opto-isolator, inverter, igbt

What's the proper schematic for driving the IGBT (IRG4BC20UD) from a microcontroller (MSP430-g2553) pin through the optocoupler (FOD3184)? I am going to design a full bridge inverter to drive 9W CFLs (220V/50Hz)? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I have no idea, why don't you start first?

Comment: The [internet is so silent](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/how-to-drive-an-igbt-with-an-optocoupler.105858/) when you ask questions in certain way. Leaving the finger shaking aside, what you seem to want is something [like this](http://www.irf.com/pressroom/articles/631pet1005.pdf), albeit not using the exact same chips.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible schematics. IGBTs are best driven with high voltage high-pulsed-current-drive 15V/-5V drive and of course you want isolation or you wouldn't be asking for an opto. You may be able to get away with +15/0V drive in some circumstances.

[Here is one chip](http://www.avagotech.com/cs/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheadername1=content-type&blobheadername2=Content-Disposition&blobheadername3=MDT-Type&blobheadervalue1=application%2Fpdf&blobheadervalue2=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22AV02-2930EN%2BDS%2BACPL-P340_W340%2B08Nov2011%252C0.pdf%22&blobheadervalue3=abinary%253B%2Bcharset%253DUTF-8&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1211076527240&ssbinary=true) that will do the opto part and the driver part, and is similar to the one you are wanting to use. You still have to deal with giving it +15/-5 or at least +15V/0 relative to the emitter on the high side driver.

Probably for such a low power level a bootstrap diode would be an appropriate approach (limited to +V drive only). So, something like a UF4007 connected to a low voltage supply on the mains side. Ask if you don't know what a bootstrap is, or see most any of the IR application notes on half-bridge drivers.

The LED drive circuit most recommended is the shunt circuit (have your micro drive a transistor to shunt the LED, with a series resistor or resistors to the supplies).

[image]

Comment: We can't see your actual schematic - if we could I'd we'd be able to at least offer suggestions

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for the response. Actually I am trying to develop a full bridge inverter. For the inverter, I need replicate the below circuit for each IGBT. But, my circuit is giving me no output, I believe there is something or everything wrong with the connections. Please help me with your expert opinion. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sBN0KtrWmMN2RnWVFQWjc5Njg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I hope you can see the schematic now in the above comment?

Comment: Did you have a chance to see my schematic? I am looking forward to your response. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the opto-isolation used in the attached link

http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/DRM039.pdf

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi, my test circuit is working properly, thanks a lot.